# How to define with Ruby a day ago at 2:00 PM?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I need to make a search of events from yesterday at 2:00PM until now, I'm trying like this

```
events.where("DATE(created_at) >= ? and DATE(created_at) <=", (1.day.ago + 14.hours).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:'), Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:') )
```

But it shows empty... but when I removed the " %H:%M:" from the formatting text, I get them as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you need to get a handle on what "yesterday at 2:00pm is" which I'd translate to:

```
DateTime.now.yesterday.beginning_of_day.change(:hour => 14)
```

Many of the solutions posted here suggest adding 14 hours to the beginning of yesterday, but this is wrong. **Remember Daylight Saving Time**! What is safer is simply changing the hour to the appropriate value.

There are not 24 hours in a day. There are 23, 24 and 25 depending on what day it is. To demonstrate this, look at the DST transition periods:

```
Time.zone = 'EST5EDT'
DateTime.parse('2012-03-12 12:34:56 -0500').to_time_in_current_zone.yesterday.beginning_of_day + 14.hours
# => Sun, 11 Mar 2012 15:00:00 EDT -04:00
```

That's 3pm because 1am to 2am didn't happen. Using `change` you should always get the correct results:

```
DateTime.parse('2012-03-12 12:34:56 -0500').to_time_in_current_zone.yesterday.beginning_of_day.change(:hour => 14)
# => Sun, 11 Mar 2012 14:00:00 EDT -04:00
```

Often you can use the `BETWEEN` operator to simplify your date computations, too, but in your case since you're fetching between that point in time and right now, presuming you don't have events in the future you can omit the one bound. Also ActiveRecord should handle formatting DateTime values properly when making queries so the `strftime` call is often counter-productive as you could easily get it wrong.

```
events.where("DATE(created_at) >= ?", DateTime.now.yesterday.beginning_of_day.change(:hour => 14))
```

If you do have to deal with future events for whatever reason:

```
events.where("DATE(created_at) BETWEEN ? AND ?", DateTime.now.yesterday.beginning_of_day.change(:hour => 14), DateTime.now)
```

Keep in mind that it's usually advantageous to store your database times in UTC and convert from local-time to UTC when doing queries. Storing time-zone tainted values in a database can create all manner of trouble if you need to deal with multiple time-zones simultaneously.

Comment: Good call on the DST issue. I hate DST even more than timezones.

Comment: Thanks a lot! it seems to work now, gonna make some tests and let you know about it!

Comment: Always test your boundary conditions if you can. For example, make sure you don't subject people in Arizona to DST when they're not in that kind of time zone.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Rails (and it looks like you are), you want

```
1.day.ago.beginning_of_day + 14.hours
```

because

```
1.day.ago
```

will give you exactly 24 hours ago.

Edit: Tadman's post is more precise as it covers the transition to and from Daylight Savings Time.  Use

```
DateTime.now.yesterday.beginning_of_day.change(:hour => 14)
```

Comment: +1: didnt know about this method: beginning_of_day ! sweet ruby!

Comment: it's rails actually, but yes... super handy!

Comment: That's not correct. That will give you 23, 24 or 25 hours ago depending on the day if you're in a time-zone that observes Daylight Saving Time.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you're converting your `created_at` timestamps to dates when your search conditions need to be aware of the time of day. You can fix this by dropping the `DATE()` calls in your query and you should probably switch to `BETWEEN` while you're at it.

Secondly, your date arithmetic, `1.day.ago + 14.hours`, won't necessarily produce "yesterday at 14:00" as `1.day.ago` includes a time of day. You can fix this by using `Date.yesterday + 14.hours`.

Thirdly, you don't have to `strftime` things yourself, ActiveRecord will handle the stringification all by itself.

Fourthly, you might have a timezone problem as a side effect of manually using `strftime` but neglecting to include the timezone. If you let ActiveRecord translate your times to what the database expects then it will apply the necessary timezone adjustments for you.

I think you want something more like this:

```
events.where(
    'created_at between :start and :end',
    :start => Date.yesteday + 14.hours,
    :end   => Time.now
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for

> events.where(" created_at between ? and ? ",
>   Time.local(1.day.ago.year, 1.day.ago.month, 1.day.ago.day, 14,
>   0).to_s(:db), Time.now.to_s(:db))

Comment: this will get from 2 am! i guess u have to change to 14 instead 2 for the hours!

Answer (score 0):

I guess that would do the job:

```
a = 1.day.ago.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
yyyy, mm, dd = $1, $2, $3 if a =~ /(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)/
t = Time.mktime(yyyy, mm, dd, 14)
events.where("DATE(created_at) >= ? and DATE(created_at) <=", t.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:'), Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:') )
```